# Building with QtCreator and giving capability to Pcap

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator, pcap, capability

I am building a sniffer with Qt as GUI, pcap as capture library and QtCreator as GUI under Ubuntu 10.04.

Problem is: Before I can capture packets, since my app is not meant to be run as root, I need to

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip my_program
```

and at every build, this capability is overwritten. Any idea how i can automate this process using QtCreator? I tried to add the command to the build steps after the Make step, but it doesn't seem to work that way, probably because of the "sudo" required...

Thank you!

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you add this functionality into a `QThread` and run that when the application is ready.

Comment: You think the application could "sudo setcap" itself?